# How can I test contracts with NUnit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have an abstract class with abstract methods, and it's subclasses that override this method must uphold a certain contract. (I do **not** mean .NET's code contracts, just the concept of code contracts itself). The test code for this contract can be the same. How can I test this contract with NUnit on all the subclasses while maintaining DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle?

(I'm stuck with NUnit because of reasons out of my control and irrelevant to this question).

Comment: What do you want to test other than the specific implementation of a given derived class?

Comment: I want to test the contract that all the derived classes have to implement. If I write the tests for each of the derived classes, it will be the same exact code, except for the class names.

Answer (score 3):

you can create a base test class with an abstract method to get the implementation to test, then create a derived instance per derived class to test.

Something like this

```
[TestClass]
public abstract class TestBase
{
     protected abstract IMyInterface GetObjectToTest();

     [Test]
     public void TestMethod()
     {
          IMyInterface objectToTest = GetObjectToTest();
          //Do your generic test of all implementations of IMyInterface
          objectToTest.Setup();
          //...
          Assert.Equal(objectToTest.Property,100);
          //etc
     }
}

[TestClass]
public class ConcreteTestClass : TestBase
{
    protected override GetObjectToTest()
    {
         return new ConcreteImplementationOfIMyObject();
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestConcreteImplementationOfIMyObjectSpecificMethod()
    {   
        //test method for stuff which only applies to ConcreteImplementationOfIMyObject types
    }
 }
```

Using this method you put all of your tests which apply to all instances of the interface in the base class, and then put any tests which are specific to a particular implementation in that test class.